# How to prove that $m!n!(m+n)!|(2m)!(2n)!$ for every pair of positive integers $(m,n)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, factorial, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I want to prove that

> For every pair of positive integers $(m,n)$, the statement $m!n!(m+n)!|(2m)!(2n)!$ holds.

which is equivalent to

> For every pair of positive integers $(m,n)$, the statement $$
> \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac m{p^i}\right\rfloor+
> \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac n{p^i}\right\rfloor+
> \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac {m+n}{p^i}\right\rfloor
> \le\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac {2m}{p^i}\right\rfloor+
> \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac {2n}{p^i}\right\rfloor$$ holds for every prime number $p$.

I have tried setting $m=ap+c,n=bp+d$ with $a,b,c,d$ nonnegative integers and $c,d<p$. From that, the inequality becomes
$$
a+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac a{p^i}\right\rfloor+
b+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac b{p^i}\right\rfloor+
a+b+\left\lfloor\frac{c+d}{p}\right\rfloor+
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac{a+b}{p^i}+\frac {c+d}{p^{i+1}}\right\rfloor
\\\le
2a+\left\lfloor\frac{2c}{p}\right\rfloor+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac {2a}{p^i}+\frac{2c}{p^{i+1}}\right\rfloor\\+
2b+\left\lfloor\frac{2d}{p}\right\rfloor+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac {2b}{p^i}+\frac{2d}{p^{i+1}}\right\rfloor$$
$$\iff \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac a{p^i}\right\rfloor+
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac b{p^i}\right\rfloor+
\left\lfloor\frac{c+d}{p}\right\rfloor+
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac{a+b+\frac {c+d}{p}}{p^i}\right\rfloor
\\\le
\left\lfloor\frac{2c}{p}\right\rfloor+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac {2a+\frac{2c}{p}}{p^i}\right\rfloor\\+
\left\lfloor\frac{2d}{p}\right\rfloor+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac {2b+\frac{2d}{p}}{p^i}\right\rfloor\text.$$

After that, I tried splitting cases based on whether $2c\ge p$, whether $2d\ge p$, and whether $c+d\ge p$. The case where $2c<p$, $2d\ge p$, and $c+d\ge p$ becomes
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac a{p^i}\right\rfloor+
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac b{p^i}\right\rfloor+
1+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac{a+b+1}{p^i}\right\rfloor
\le
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac {2a}{p^i}\right\rfloor+
1+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac {2b+1}{p^i}\right\rfloor$$
$$\iff
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac a{p^i}\right\rfloor+
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac b{p^i}\right\rfloor+
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac{a+b+1}{p^i}\right\rfloor
\le
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac {2a}{p^i}\right\rfloor+
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac {2b+1}{p^i}\right\rfloor$$
$$\iff
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left(
\left\lfloor\frac a{p^i}\right\rfloor+
\left\lfloor\frac b{p^i}\right\rfloor+
\left\lfloor\frac{a+b+1}{p^i}\right\rfloor\right)
\le
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left(
\left\lfloor\frac {2a}{p^i}\right\rfloor+
\left\lfloor\frac {2b+1}{p^i}\right\rfloor\right)\text.$$

How to carry on from there?

Answer (score 0):

Let  $x=\frac{m}{p^i}$ and $y=\frac{n}{p^i}.$

Thus, by your work it's enough to prove that
$$[2x]+[2y]\geq[x]+[y]+[x+y],$$ 
which is not so hard.

Comment: By $[x]$, do you mean the floor function?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: $[2\{x\}]+[2\{y\}]\geq\{x+y\},$ doesn't hold if ${x}={y}=\frac14$.

Comment: In your case $\{x+y\}=0.$ I can write a full proof if you want. It remains to write also three cases.

Comment: What is $x$ and $y$? And why does $\{x+y\}=0$?

Comment: We can think that they are non-negative numbers. $\{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\}=\{\frac{1}{2}\}=0.$

Comment: How to apply that to my work? And what is ${x}$, fractional part? Then ${\frac12}=\frac12$, not $0$.

Comment: Because we need to prove that $\left[\frac{2n}{p^i}\right]+\left[\frac{2m}{p^i}\right]\geq\left[\frac{m+n}{p^i}\right]+\left[\frac{n}{p^i}\right]+\left[\frac{m}{p^i}\right]$. Here $x=\frac{m}{p^i}$ and $y=\frac{n}{p^i}.$

Comment: And what is x, fractional part? Then $\{1/2\}=1/2$, not $0$.

Comment: Yes, it's was total wrong, Black out. Sorry.  but in all case it's not so hard. I see a proof of course.

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate. Thank you anyway.